# My Open email activities in dynamics CRM are not being send even after due date

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a CRM form, in that some scheduled email activities are there with due date. after reaching that due date open email activities should process and an email should be send. after sending mail open email activities should become closed.
but from last week my open email activities are in same state even due date completed. i am not able to get reason. can any one of you help me from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduled Email Activities with due date are not sending even after completing due date. for this purpose i have created Tack scheduler(console App) in C#. it will run every day and process email activities on that day. i have hosted in worker role of azure so it is running daily and sending email activities.